# Installation of Miniconda fails with illegal instruction

Tags: bash, software-installation, python

On executing bash (Miniconda installer) I am getting

```
installing: python-3.6.5-hc3d631a_2 ...
Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86.sh: line 355:  3886 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) "$PREFIX/pkgs/python-3.6.5-hc3d631a_2/bin/python" -E -s "$PREFIX"/pkgs/.install.py $INST_OPT --root-prefix="$PREFIX" --link-dist="$1"
```

I fell back to earlier installers to see if they would work, as you see, but the same error always comes up.  That was the only idea I had.

This is a 32-bit installer for my 32-bit system, Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver), Kernel 5.4.0-77-generic i686 MATE 1.20.1 running on a Thinkpad T43.  (There's nothing I can upgrade this to that works).

Comment: FYI: Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that in April reached it's EOL.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ or a semi-recent UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for Lubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Budgie; https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-reaches-end-of-kubuntu-support/